# rails with capistrano and bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I run on hostingrails.com

```
* executing "cd /home/p712738r/apps/energynowtv.com/current &&  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/bundle install vendor/gems"
    servers: ["energynowtv.com"]
    [energynowtv.com] executing command
 ** [out :: energynowtv.com] /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Why happens ?
Thanks all you

Answer (score 0):

problem is (I think) that you have both rvm and system wide ruby install.
This command when executed, runs system wide version of bundler (you probably have 1.9.1 installed) instead of the rvm one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your `rvm_ruby_string` in your `deploy.rb` file. Here's mine:

```
require "rvm/capistrano" # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ree-1.8.7-2011.03@rails3' # Or whatever env you want it to run in.
set :rvm_type, :user
```

The string `'ree-1.8.7-2011.03@rails3'` should be the same one in your `.rvmrc` in the root of your app.